# Good way to HTTP DELETE an object with a composite primary key

Tags: rest, http

I need to create an endpoint to delete an object with a composite id.

I dont know what the best way to do that for a resfull api :

1. use queryparams : DELETE /objetcs?idPart1=1&idPart2=1
2. use the body : DELETE /objets body : { idPart1 : 1,idPart2 : 1 }
3. something i didnt thought about

Thanks for your help

nothing was tested since that's a technical question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't HTTP:DELETE *objects*, you HTTP:DELETE *resources*.

> You have to learn how to trigger business activity as a side effect of moving documents around. -- [Jim Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s)

Deleting a resource will normally use the same URI as getting the resource.

```
GET /objects/123/456
DELETE /objects/123/456
```

We do it this way so that general purpose HTTP caches can understand what is going on, and do the right thing with their local copies of prior responses (see [RFC 9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons))

---

> use the body

DELETE-with-a-body is not a good choice.  See [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-delete)

> A client SHOULD NOT generate content in a DELETE request unless it is made directly to an origin server that has previously indicated, in or out of band, that such a request has a purpose and will be adequately supported.

Notice that "directly to" -- if anybody puts a general-purpose proxy between your client(s) and your server, all bets are off.

I would insist on an impressively thorough architectural decision record before I would accept a DELETE-with-a-body PR into any of my projects.

---

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect. -- [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-delete)

A viable alternative to using DELETE is [to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

```
POST /objects/123/456
Content-Type: text/plain

Bob,

Please remove /objects/123/456 from the catalog of resources that are accessible via the API.
```

Remember, the most common interface to access resources on the world wide web is via a browser rendering HTML, and that interface does not have affordances for DELETE.  Yet somehow, the web was catastrophically successful.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the best choice depends on your specific use case and the level of RESTful adherence you want to maintain in your API. If security and clarity are top priorities, using a request body or a custom approach may be preferable. However, if you prefer to stick with more conventional RESTful practices, using query parameters to identify the resource to delete could work well.

Answer (score 0):

request body in `DELETE` operation is not advised.

I think your best bet would be to pass both keys in the path parameters

```
api/v1/objects/:key1/:key2

api/v1/cars/big/red
```